# Populate table from array using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, populate

I have an array of 16 elements that I want to fill a table. I want it to have 2 rows with 8 cells in each row which is filled with the array. My problem is that when the table is populated, the table populates all elements into one row. I have not had much experience with JQuery and I want to try to get this to work. Any help is appreciated! Here is my code:

```
//**********Javascript & JQuery**********
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var count = 0;
var totalCells = 8;

function writeTable() {
    var $table = $('#summaryOfResults');

    //Array always includes enough elements to fill an entire row, which is 8 cells. Outer loop determines how many rows to make.
    //Inner loop determines the elements to print in the cells for that row.
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length / 8; i++) {
        $table.find('#body').append('<tr>');
        for (var j = 0; j < totalCells; j++) {
            $table.append('<td>' + array[count] + '</td>');
            count++;
        }
        $table.append('</tr>');
    }
}

//**********HTML**********
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="resultsTable">
    <table id='summaryOfResults' border='1'>
        <tbody id="body">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>n<sub>i</sub></th>
                <th>n<sub>f</sub></th>
                <th>E<sub>i</sub> (J)</th>
                <th>E<sub>f</sub> (J)</th>
                <th>&Delta;E (J)</th>
                <th>&Delta;E (kJ/mol)</th>
                <th>&lambda; (nm)</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="tableButtons">
    <button id='copyButton' onclick=''>Copy Table</button>
    <button id='clear' onclick='clearTable();'>Clear Table</button>
    <button id='write' onclick='writeTable();'>Write Table</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you have to reset `count` on every click.
Next, you have to specify where exactly the `<td>` elements have to be appended to. As for now, you're appending them directly to the `<table>` :

```
// your declaration of the table element:
var $table = $('#summaryOfResults');
// ...
// then in nested loop, you're appending the cells directly to the table:
$table.append('<td>' + array[count] + '</td>');
```

The last thing - `.append('</tr>')` is not a proper way to create an element object, it should be `'<tr/>'` , or `'<tr></tr>'`.

---

This should be what you're looking for:

```
function writeTable() {
    // cache <tbody> element:
    var tbody = $('#body');
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length / 8; i++) {
        // create an <tr> element, append it to the <tbody> and cache it as a variable:
        var tr = $('<tr/>').appendTo(tbody);
        for (var j = 0; j < totalCells; j++) {
            // append <td> elements to previously created <tr> element:
            tr.append('<td>' + array[count] + '</td>');
            count++;
        }
    }
    // reset the count:
    count = 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8a6kkzuw/)

---

Alternatively, make a HTML string and append it to the table outside of the loop:

```
function writeTable() {
    // declare html variable (a string holder):
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length / 8; i++) {
        // add opening <tr> tag to the string:
        html += '<tr>';
        for (var j = 0; j < totalCells; j++) {
            // add <td> elements to the string:
            html += '<td>' + array[count] + '</td>';
            count++;
        }
        // add closing </tr> tag to the string:
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    //append created html to the table body:
    $('#body').append(html);
    // reset the count:
    count = 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ca9vzou/)

Comment: Thanks for this! I need to learn more about how the append in jquery, not sure why or how the TD elements can be appended to the <tr></tr>. I thought it would have to be between the opening tag and closing tag.